# Java issue String.split()

Tags: java, string, split

I have a question about `java.lang.String.split()`.

```
String str = "aaaaa";
String[] str1 = str.split("a");
str = "aaaaa ";
String[] str2 = str.split("a");

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str1));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str2));
```

Result is

```
str1 == null
str2 == ["", "", "", "", "", " "]
```

Why `str1` result that?

Comment: "str1 == null" no it's not, it's a zero-length array.

Comment: From the documentation ["Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)). In the first instance *every element* is a trailing empty string, so the array is empty. In the second instance, there are no trailing empty strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`str1` is actually an empty `String` array, not `null`.

> **String[] java.lang.String.split(String regex)**
>
> Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.
>
> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. **Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.**

If the result contains only empty strings, they are all removed and the result `str1` ends up being an empty array.

That is not the case in the `str2` example, where the last string is not empty (it contains a single space) and therefore the (not trailing) empty strings are not removed from the result.

Comment: @AshishkumarSingh The question was about `str1` only, but I added an explanation about `str2` too.

Answer (score 1):

@Eran provided provided the proper explanation. Just to add that if you still want to keep the array with empty Strings, you can use

```
String[] s_ = str.split("a", 6);
System.out.println("s_ : " + Arrays.toString(s_));
```

, or any other limit (the number of times the pattern is applied) greater than 6, instead of the simple split.

The latter will print,

```
s_ : [, , , , , ]
```